# Dynamic URL Rewrite from GET

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewrite-module

I want to rewrite my URLs which are based upon directories I have
My directories look like this:

```
index.php
galleries
   -Party Weekend
       -2014
          -Bunchofimages.png
   -Other pics
       -Pictures.png
```

And the urls look like:

```
example.com/?f=/Party%20Weekend/2014
```

And I was looking for something like

```
example.com/Party-Weekend/2014
```

(Can be a dash or a + sign, doesn't really matter)

(Using `.htaccess` seems like the best option but I have no experience with `.htaccess` at all)

Also do I need to customize every single folder in the rewrite engine or can this be done dynamicly? (So I don't need to make a new rule for every folder I create)

I tried this but doesn't rewrite anything at all

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?f=$1 [L]
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You can simply do a str_replace in PHP of "%20" and replace it by "+" or "-".

Comment: @Dev'Hamz But main goal is to remove the ?f= part

Comment: I would do like that : str_replace("/?f=", "", $url);

Comment: @Dev'Hamz Then I need to use a str_replace in my get parameter as well right? since otherwise that doesn't know where to start and stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+\?f=([^\ &]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/galleries%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?f=$1 [L]
```

There *may* be some encoding issues related to the spaces in your folder names, so you may either need some combination of the `NE` or `B` flags in side the brackets.

Comment: Thanks a lot this was really close to the solution
Solution:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?f=$1

Answer (score -2):

Using .htacces is the best and only way
you don't have to customize all folders you do it all dynamically
please go to this page for more details its easy
URL Rewriting for Beginners : 
http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: That's no answer, that's just a link which may be broken in the future.

Comment: @Reeno
I have something like this but it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\$ /test/?f=$1 [L]

P.S That's what I could find out using that link

Comment: @TheJetse: You should add this to your question so everybody sees your efforts to solve it. I just had a quick look at it, why do you use a backslash at the end of the pattern and not a forward slash?

Comment: @Reeno Ok I will but it's not rewriting ANYTHING at all(placed the .htaccess in almost every folder possible to make sure but doesn't help :P )